# Terminology - one-time code generation directives

Tags: c-preprocessor, code-generation, terminology, template-engine, preprocessor

Is there a such thing as a preprocessor whose statements, once processed, disappear completely and get replaced by the target language syntax permanently?

I want to research it on the web but I don't know what term to search for. If I search for "code generator", "templating language", "preprocessor directives", "mixins", "annotations" I get generators whose input becomes the source of truth.

The closest thing I can think of is a [macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)#Text-substitution_macros).

**What I'm trying to do**

I often have to write code that is verbose and unnecessary manual labor and am looking for a smarter way to input at least the majority of it and have it automatically transformed and only source-control the output (and hand edit if necessary). For example:

- Java code - Instead of writing getters/setters, javadoc (perhaps the transformer can be a maven plugin)
- HTML - I just want to add URLs, and have my preprocessor automatically convert them to links, images, videos, audio etc. depending on the file extension with some regex substitution (currently I run a perl script via a cron job)

I just want to use it as my own shorthand and not enforce it in my project and make the output editable so that others have to learn a new framework or language (like Protobuf, Stringtemplate, GWT, C hash-defines, PHP, JSP etc).

There should be no direct clue that I used a template/preprocessor to generate it.

Comment: Maybe scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a "program transformation system".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation.   (This is a superset of "transpilers" [ugly term]).

A good source-to-source transformation system will let you apply rewrite rules of the form of:

```
  if you see *this*, replace it by *that* if *this_condition*.
```

You can then take  your source code, and run a set of rewrite rules across that code to change it.

The resulting code is "transformed"; the rewrite rules are  not visible.

Comment: Any examples? Something that is a maven plugin would be ideal. Possibly http://www.smooks.org/ ?

Comment: See rewrite rules http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html for my company's DMS program transformation system.  (The example is too long to put into a comment or an answer here). DMS could be used as a Maven action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Transpiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) is one way to describe it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please post as an answer so I can give you credit.